# Wicket - Internet Explorer double submit

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, wicket

I have a big problem with Internet Explorer 7 and 8.

SITUATION:

I have a FORM that build a Medical Prescription. When I hit the save button, the script saves the DomainObject on DB and set a boolean property (of panel where the form is added) called "saved" to true and a byte[] property called PDF with bytestream.

On RenderHead of Panel, I read this boolean and, if is true, I force the trigger of a hidden button with this code:

```
String js = "$('#" + printPDF.getMarkupId() + "').click();";    
response.renderOnDomReadyJavaScript(js);
```

The button executes this code:

```
    ResourceStreamRequestHandler handler = new ResourceStreamRequestHandler(new ByteArrayResourceStream(pdf, "application/pdf"));
    handler.setFileName("foo.pdf");             
    RequestCycle.get().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(handler);
```

This code work perfecly on FF and Chrome. The Browser download windows appears and the user can save the PDF on HD.

Unfortunally, Internet Explorer has that damn security behavior that is triggered when a site require something to download. That warning require a user validation. A yellow Bar appear and the user is force to hit "Download".

[screenshot http://imageshack.us/a/img198/1438/securityg.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img198/1438/securityg.jpg)

When I hit Download File, the form is submitted again with the exact state I had when I hit save the first time. So no previous INSERT on DB is already committed; The Session is resetted to the previous state etc...

The result is a double INSERT on DB of the Domain Ojbect.

Any clue to resolve this?

Comment: NOTE: If disabled the security advice in Internet Explorer Security Setting, the insert is not doubled.

Comment: The easiest, although not the cleanest thing is obviously to stop the double insert (by recording the last inserted ID in the session for example). But this sounds very much like an IE bug, so your options are probably limited.

Comment: Unfortunally, as said above, IE save the state of session as it is in the first submit so any value I set in sessione between first and second submit is lost. The only solution I found is generate a unique and specific String code (so both DomainObject generate the same code). Set a UNIQUE column on DB and catch the ORACLE exception.

Comment: IE can't "save the state of session", as the session is maintained on the server side. IE has no access to it other than through your code.

Comment: I don't know how IE "talks" to wicket. What I know is that after the first submit, every change on Wicket's WebSession is lost in the second submit has it never happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you click download link programaticly instead to redirect browser to an URL or open an URL by JS window.open(url). Click a link looks like an unwanted operation that is sometimes restricted by browser.